# TimeStamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP shows incorrect time (2 hours earlier)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I have a row in my table where i use the TimeStamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP that automatically enters the time when user registers in the form. However it is showing the incorrect time. It is showing 2 hours earlier.

In the php.ini I have changed the date.timezone to `date.timezone = Europe/Oslo`but it will still show the wrong time.

Comment: PHP settings don't affect `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in MySQL.

Comment: Also tried using the SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00' but wont affect anything. Do i have to restart anything in order to make it work?